# Why do I get a '1292 Truncated' warning when importing a CSV with time data to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, csv, time-format

I'm importing a csv file to MySQL. Part of the data is a time field. I'm utilizing the `TIME_FORMAT()` to set the desire format. However, I'm not getting what I need. Here is the code that I'm using to format the time field.

```
CREATE TABLE `COURSE_SECTION` (
    `C_SEC_ID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `COURSE_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `TERM_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `SEC_NUM` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `F_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `MTG_DAYS` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    `START_TIME` TIME NOT NULL,
    `END_TIME` TIME NOT NULL,
    `LOC_ID` INTEGER,
    `MAX_ENRL` INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY (`COURSE_ID`)
    REFERENCES course (`COURSE_ID`)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION,
FOREIGN KEY (`TERM_ID`)
    REFERENCES term (`TERM_ID`)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION,
FOREIGN KEY (`F_ID`)
    REFERENCES faculty (`F_ID`)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION,
FOREIGN KEY (`LOC_ID`)
    REFERENCES location (`LOC_ID`)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

csv input:

```
C_SEC_ID, COURSE_ID, TERM_ID, SEC_NUM, F_ID,    MTG_DAYS, START_TIME, END_TIME, LOC_ID, MAX_ENRL
Number,   Number,    Number,  Number,  Number,  String,   Date/Time,  String,   Number, Number
1,        1,         4,       1,       2,       MWF,      10:00 AM,   10:50 AM, 1,      140
2,1,4,2,3,TR,9:30 AM,10:45 AM,7,35
3,1,4,3,3,MWF,8:00 AM,8:50 AM,2,35
4,2,4,1,4,TR,11:00 AM,12:15 AM,6,35
5,2,5,2,4,TR,2:00 PM,3:15 PM,6,35
6,3,5,1,1,MWF,9:00 AM,9:50 AM,5,30
7,3,5,2,1,MWF,10:00 AM,10:50 AM,5,30
8,4,5,1,5,TR,8:00 AM,9:15 AM,3,35
9,5,5,1,2,MWF,2:00 PM,2:50 PM,5,35
10,5,5,2,2,MWF,3:00 PM,3:50 PM,5,35
11,1,6,1,1,MTWRF,8:00 AM,9:30 AM,1,50
12,2,6,1,2,MTWRF,8:00 AM,9:30 AM,6,35
13,3,6,1,3,MTWRF,8:00 AM,9:30 AM,5,35
```

code to import csv:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path to the file/Course_Section.csv' 
INTO TABLE COURSE_SECTION
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 2 ROWS
(C_SEC_ID,COURSE_ID,TERM_ID,SEC_NUM,F_ID,MTG_DAYS,@START_TIME,@END_TIME,LOC_ID,MAX_ENRL)
SET START_TIME = TIME_FORMAT(@START_TIME, '%h:%i %p'),
END_TIME = TIME_FORMAT(@END_TIME, '%h:%i %p');
```

result in the table is `03:15:00` instead of `03:15 PM`

I have also tried the following code with no success:

```
SET START_TIME = TIME_FORMAT(CAST(@START_TIME AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8), '%h:%i %p'),
END_TIME = TIME_FORMAT(CAST(@END_TIME AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8), '%h:%i %p');
```

The outcome is the same as before.

With the following code I got the correct value, but with warnings:

```
SET START_TIME = TIME_FORMAT(
    CAST(
        CONCAT(CASE WHEN RIGHT(@START_TIME,2) = 'PM' 
            THEN
                HOUR(@START_TIME) + 12 
            ELSE 
                HOUR(@START_TIME) END, ':',
                MINUTE(@START_TIME)) AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8), '%T'),
```

And the warning is as follows:

```
1292 Truncated incorrect time value: '10:00 AM'
```

What does the warning mean, exactly, and how I can get rid of it?

What am I missing in my code?

Comment: What is your actual problem?  Can you share full sample input data, and what is going wrong with the import?

Comment: and also, please tell us exactly how you came to the conclusion that the "result in the table" is 03:15:00.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

`TIME_FORMAT(@END_TIME, '%r');`

and for `@START_TIME` as well, without using any custom function. Check this fiddle as well:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/59828

Comment: mysql has its own built in TIME_FORMAT function to format only time part

Comment: I'm not `SELECT`, I'm `LOAD DATA`. I have to modify your recommendation to `SET START_TIME = TIME_FORMAT(@START_TIME, '%r'),
    END_TIME = TIME_FORMAT(@END_TIME, '%r');`. The result is the same as before... `03:15:00` instead of `03:15 PM` or 15:15:00`.

Comment: may be it is a little long way. What I think that you could just import the data without any warning by LOADATA. And then use select into statement  to insert into the right table with right data with SELECT statement without warning to get the job done